# How to mutate for all observations with the same ID?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the following data set:

```
Country     State      Town    Color      YLocation    Height
958         115         A       Red         1.23        Tall
958         115         A       Blue        5.97        Short
958         115         A       Yellow      4.83        Short
958         116         B       Red         3.93        Tall
958         116         B       Blue        2.27        Short
958         116         B       Yellow      9.91        Short
959         180         A       Blue        6.69        Short
959         180         A       Red         5.49        Tall
959         180         A       Green       3.27        Short
959         180         A       Red         3.99        Short
```

I want to create a new column that shows the YLocation for that Town if the Color is red and Height is 'Tall'. So I would like the above table to become:

```
Country     State      Town    Color      YLocation  Height  RedLocation     
958         115         A       Red         1.23    Tall          1.23
958         115         A       Blue        5.97    Short         1.23
958         115         A       Yellow      4.83    Short         1.23
958         116         B       Red         3.93    Tall          3.93
958         116         B       Blue        2.27    Short         3.93
958         116         B       Yellow      9.91    Short         3.93
959         180         A       Blue        6.69    Short         5.49
959         180         A       Red         5.49    Tall          5.49
959         180         A       Green       3.27    Short         5.49
959         180         A       Red         3.99    Short         5.49
```

In short, I want the new column to identify the Ylocation for a town when the Color column is equal to red *and when 'Height' is equal to 'Tall'*. Unfortunately, there isn't a unique identifier for 'Town/State/Country' (and it won't be possible to create one since some of the data in those columns are numbers), so I am guessing that the solution will use the `group_by` command in order to make sure the RedLocation variable is mapped to the correct observations.

Data:

```
structure(list(Country = c(958L, 958L, 958L, 958L, 958L, 958L, 
959L, 959L, 959L, 959L), State = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 116L, 116L, 
116L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L), Town = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "A"), Color = c("Red", "Blue ", "Yellow", 
"Red", "Blue ", "Yellow", "Blue ", "Red", "Green", "Red"), Height = c("Tall", 
"Short", "Short", "Tall", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Tall", 
"Short", "Short"), Ylocation = c(1.23, 5.97, 4.83, 3.93, 2.27, 
9.91, 6.69, 5.49, 3.27, 3.99)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match` to get the index after grouping by

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    group_by(Country, State, Town) %>% 
    mutate(RedLocation = Ylocation[match('Red', Color)]) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 9 x 6    
#  Country State Town  Color    Ylocation RedLocation
#    <int> <int> <chr> <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     958   115 A     "Red"         1.23        1.23
#2     958   115 A     "Blue "       5.97        1.23
#3     958   115 A     "Yellow"      4.83        1.23
#4     958   116 B     "Red"         3.93        3.93
#5     958   116 B     "Blue "       2.27        3.93
#6     958   116 B     "Yellow"      9.91        3.93
#7     959   180 A     "Blue "       6.69        5.49
#8     959   180 A     "Red"         5.49        5.49
#9     959   180 A     "Green"       3.27        5.49
```

#### Update

If there are multiple columns, an option is to use `across` to loop over the columns

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(Country, State, Town) %>%
     mutate(across(c(Color, Height), ~ 
          Ylocation[match(c('Red', 'Tall'), ., nomatch = 0)],
            .names = '{.col}_new')) %>%
     ungroup %>%
     rename(RedLocation = Color_new, TallLocation = Height_new)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 8
#   Country State Town  Color    Height Ylocation RedLocation TallLocation
#     <int> <int> <chr> <chr>    <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     958   115 A     "Red"    Tall        1.23        1.23         1.23
# 2     958   115 A     "Blue "  Short       5.97        1.23         1.23
# 3     958   115 A     "Yellow" Short       4.83        1.23         1.23
# 4     958   116 B     "Red"    Tall        3.93        3.93         3.93
# 5     958   116 B     "Blue "  Short       2.27        3.93         3.93
# 6     958   116 B     "Yellow" Short       9.91        3.93         3.93
# 7     959   180 A     "Blue "  Short       6.69        5.49         5.49
# 8     959   180 A     "Red"    Tall        5.49        5.49         5.49
# 9     959   180 A     "Green"  Short       3.27        5.49         5.49
#10     959   180 A     "Red"    Short       3.99        5.49         5.49
```

---

Or if we need both columns to be matched, an option is

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(Country, State, Town) %>% 
    mutate(RedTallLocation = Ylocation[match('Red Tall', paste(Color, Height))]) %>%
    ungroup
# A tibble: 10 x 7
#   Country State Town  Color    Height Ylocation RedTallLocation
#     <int> <int> <chr> <chr>    <chr>      <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1     958   115 A     "Red"    Tall        1.23            1.23
# 2     958   115 A     "Blue "  Short       5.97            1.23
# 3     958   115 A     "Yellow" Short       4.83            1.23
# 4     958   116 B     "Red"    Tall        3.93            3.93
# 5     958   116 B     "Blue "  Short       2.27            3.93
# 6     958   116 B     "Yellow" Short       9.91            3.93
# 7     959   180 A     "Blue "  Short       6.69            5.49
# 8     959   180 A     "Red"    Tall        5.49            5.49
# 9     959   180 A     "Green"  Short       3.27            5.49
#10     959   180 A     "Red"    Short       3.99            5.49
```

---

Or create the expression with `&` , wrap with `which` and extract the first position (`[1]`)

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(Country, State, Town) %>% 
     mutate(RedTallLocation = Ylocation[which(Color == 'Red' &
            Height == 'Tall')[1]]) %>% 
     ungroup
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[Color == 'Red', RedLocation := Ylocation[1], .(Country, State, Town)]
```

---

Or in `base R`, we can subset the data where the 'Color' is 'Red' and then do a `merge`

```
df2 <- subset(df1, Color == 'Red')[-4]
names(df2)[4] <- "RedLocation"
merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: I like the ```match``` command. I am wondering if it is possible to combine it with another requirement. For example, what if there was another column named Height, and I wanted to repeat the same task as described above, but also if 'Height' is equal to 'tall' (this is just hypothetical)? In short, I'm looking to just add a second requirement to the above question. Would it be as simple as adding a second ```match``` command?

Comment: @rogues77 I am not completely sure about your comment.  But, I updated the answer based on the description.  It is not tested though.

Comment: Please lmk if it makes sense, I might not be explaining clearly enough

Comment: @rogues77 I updated with couple of cases.  I assume one of them is what you wanted

Comment: As always, you are a genius. The idea to use ```paste ``` is simple, yet elegant. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `ave`

```
within(
  df,
  RedLocation <- ave(
    ifelse(Color == "Red", Ylocation, NA),
    Country,
    State,
    Town,
    FUN = na.omit
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  Country State Town  Color Ylocation RedLocation
1     958   115    A    Red      1.23        1.23
2     958   115    A   Blue      5.97        1.23
3     958   115    A Yellow      4.83        1.23
4     958   116    B    Red      3.93        3.93
5     958   116    B   Blue      2.27        3.93
6     958   116    B Yellow      9.91        3.93
7     959   180    A   Blue      6.69        5.49
8     959   180    A    Red      5.49        5.49
9     959   180    A  Green      3.27        5.49
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Country = c(958L, 958L, 958L, 958L, 958L, 958L, 
959L, 959L, 959L), State = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 116L, 116L, 116L,
180L, 180L, 180L), Town = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A",
"A", "A"), Color = c("Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue",
"Yellow", "Blue", "Red", "Green"), Ylocation = c(1.23, 5.97,
4.83, 3.93, 2.27, 9.91, 6.69, 5.49, 3.27)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-9L))
```